# special basis for a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be any finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$ be a basis for $X$. Now we have $\alpha_i \alpha_j \in X$. Write it as a linear combination interms of the above basis. So  you will be getting a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ say denoted by $a_{ij}$. So if you take the multiplication table of the above basis, we will be getting a matrix $A=[a_{ij}] \in M_n({\mathbb{C}}^n)$.

My question is as follows. Is there any special basis for $X$ so that each column and each row of $A$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: The multiplication table is a tensor of rank $3$, not a matrix.

Comment: Okay I didnt know that it cannot called a matrix. Then just consider that $n \times n$ array with each entry a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I need such a basis so that each column and row this array give orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

A finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra is isomorphic to 
$$
 M_{n_1}(\mathbb C) \oplus \cdots \oplus M_{n_r}(\mathbb C),
$$
where $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_r \in \mathbb N$. In particular they have a canonical basis 
$$
 \{e_{ij}^{(1)} \}_{i,j=1}^{n_1} \cup \cdots \cup \{e_{ij}^{(r)}\}_{i,j=1}^{n_r}.
$$
The matrix you are looking for is the identity matrix in $M_l\mathbb C)$, where $l = n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_r$.

Comment: If you take this canonical basis, then will its multiplication table satisfy the property I have mentioned?